# Wildlfy-Swarm Microprofile HealthCheck not responding

Tags: health-monitoring, wildfly-swarm

I'm trying to implement a microprofile `HealthCheck` in my wildfly-swarm 2017.12.1 application.

Here's the

```
@Health
@Dependent
public class SystemHealthChecker extends AbstractHealthChecker {

  @Override
  public HealthCheckResponse call() {
    boolean up;
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    long freeMemory = runtime.freeMemory();
    long totalMemory = runtime.totalMemory();
    double percentageFree = freeMemory*100/totalMemory;
    if(percentageFree < 10.0){
      up = false;
    }else{
      up = true;
    }

    Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
    attributes.put("Total Memory", totalMemory+"");
    attributes.put("Free Memory", freeMemory+"");
    attributes.put("Percentage Free Memory", percentageFree+"%");
    HealthCheckResponse response = getResponse("System-Check", attributes, up);
    return response;
  }
}
```

With `AbstractHealthChecker` as follows:

```
public abstract class AbstractHealthChecker implements HealthCheck {

  protected HealthCheckResponse getResponse(String name, Map<String, String> data, boolean up){
    HealthCheckResponseBuilder responseBuilder = HealthCheckResponse.named(name);

    responseBuilder.state(up);

    for(String key: data.keySet()){
      responseBuilder.withData(key, data.get(key));
    }
    responseBuilder.withData("Date", new Date().toString());

    return responseBuilder.build();
  }
}
```

It should check if the systems free memory is below 10%, but doen't really matter.
However, when I start the application, I get the warnings:

```
2018-01-09 15:23:28,974 WARNING [ServiceLoader] (main) Could not load service class org.wildfly.swarm.microprofile.faulttolerance.deployment.HystrixExtension
2018-01-09 15:23:28,974 WARNING [ServiceLoader] (main) Could not load service class org.wildfly.swarm.microprofile.health.deployment.HealthExtension
2018-01-09 15:23:28,974 WARNING [ServiceLoader] (main) Could not load service class org.wildfly.swarm.microprofile.metrics.deployment.MetricCdiInjectionExtension
2018-01-09 15:23:28,975 WARNING [ServiceLoader] (main) Could not load service class org.wildfly.swarm.cdi.config.deployment.InjectConfigViewExtension
2018-01-09 15:23:28,975 WARNING [ServiceLoader] (main) Could not load service class org.wildfly.swarm.microprofile.jwtauth.deployment.auth.cdi.MPJWTExtension
```

There is also no real output for the System-Check on the /health endpoint, I only get the following

```
{
  "outcome": "UP",
  "checks": []
}
```

so I assume, my HealthCheck wasn't found.
I use the following fractions.
Any idea, what is going wrong?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrs</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
    <artifactId>ejb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdi</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
    <artifactId>microprofile</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
    <artifactId>logging</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: how does your `getResponse()` look like? 
Code that works for me can be found here: https://github.com/pilhuhn/microprofile-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/de/bsd/microprofiledemo/rest/HealthDemo.java#L34

Comment: It was in the `AbstractHealthChecker` which I forgot to add. I've changed it. The abstract class in between was the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've removed the `AbstractHealthChecker` to implement the `HealthCheck` Interface directly and now it works.
Also I had a secound HealthCheck implementation which didn't seem to work with the `@Dependent` annoatation. Annotating both with `@ApplicationScoped` works fine.

So now I have:

```
@Health
@ApplicationScoped
public class SystemHealthChecker extends AbstractHealthChecker {

  @Override
  public HealthCheckResponse call() {
    boolean up;
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    long freeMemory = runtime.freeMemory();
    long totalMemory = runtime.totalMemory();
    double percentageFree = freeMemory*100/totalMemory;
    if(percentageFree < 10.0){
      up = false;
    }else{
      up = true;
    }

    Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
    attributes.put("Total Memory", totalMemory+"");
    attributes.put("Free Memory", freeMemory+"");
    attributes.put("Percentage Free Memory", percentageFree+"%");
    HealthCheckResponse response = getResponse("System-Check", attributes, up);
    return response;
  }

  private HealthCheckResponse getResponse(String name, Map<String, String> data, boolean up){
    HealthCheckResponseBuilder responseBuilder = HealthCheckResponse.named(name);

    responseBuilder.state(up);

    for(String key: data.keySet()){
        responseBuilder.withData(key, data.get(key));
    }
    responseBuilder.withData("Date", new Date().toString());

    return responseBuilder.build();
  }
}
```

And it works.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what's in `AbstractHealthChecker` it's hard to know for sure, but have you tried doing it like below? I believe that's the recommended way.

```
@Health
@ApplicationScoped
public class SystemHealthChecker implements HealthCheck {

    @Override
    public HealthCheckResponse call() {
        return HealthCheckResponse.named("sessions-check")
            .withData(sessionCountName, sessionStore.getSessions().size())
            .withData("lastCheckDate", new Date().toString())
            .up()
            .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I've forgot to add the code of the `AbstractHealthChecker`, I've fixed that. The only difference I see is that you have `@ApplicationScoped` and I have `@Dependent`. I've tried it with `@ApplicationScoped` without effect.

Comment: However, you telling me, I forget the `AbstractHealthCheck` has given me the idea, to leave it out completely and now it works. Seems like the extra layer between the Interface and the Bean didnt suffice for swarm to inject it into the health endpoint. So thank you :)